# Cant change OEM unlocking

Tags: android, motorola, unlock, fastboot

I recently installed a Pixel Experience Custom ROM on my phone. After that, for some reason, I decided to block flashing on my phone and this caused message to appear every time I boot my phone: Your Device Is Corrupt,It cant be trusted and will not BOOT visit this link on another device motorola.com/unlockbootloader.

I followed the instructions on this page and it resulted in this: `fastboot oem unlock (bootloader) Check 'OEM unlocking' in Android Settings > Developer (bootloader) Options OKAY [ 0.013s] Finished. Total time: 0.013s.` but I can't change this setting because I'm not able to enter the system. What can i do in this situation ?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to ask this question, since it's not about Android development.

Comment: Also posted to Android.SE: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/255713/44325